# Can't connect to Amazon MQ with Node.js + MQTT

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I am testing out Amazon MQ with the ActiveMQ "engine" using Node.js and MQTT, but it does not seems to be working as expected. This is what I have done so far.

I created in the AWS console choosing the following options

- Apache ActiveMQ
- Active/ stand-by broker
- mq.t2.micro

The broker was created successfully. I now have all the connection details.

I am trying to test it locally creating 2 Node.js files `producer.js` and `consumer.js`. While the `consumer.js` is up and running, when I run `producer.js` script, consumer should receive the message.

This is my `consumer.js`

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')

const config = {
    username: `myusernmae`,
    password: `mypassword`,
    mqEndpoint: `wss://b-xxxxxx-d21c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-1.mq.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:61619`, // same endpoint used by producer.js - I got this from WSS section of connections section of the broker
    clientId: 'my_client_id',
}

const client = mqtt.connect(config.mqEndpoint, {
   username: config.username,
   password: config.password,
    clientId: config.clientId,
});

// Once connected subscribe to the topic
client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log("connected")
    client.subscribe(topic, function (err) {
        if(err) console.log(err)
    })
})

client.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log("error")
    console.log(error)
})

// Log messages
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log(`message received on ${topic}: ${message.toString()}`)
})

console.log("Consumer script has been run");
```

This is my `producer.js`:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')

const config = {
    username: `myusernmae`,
    password: `mypassword`,
    host: `wss://b-xxxxxx-d21c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-1.mq.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`,// same endpoint used by consumer.js - I got this from WSS section of connections section of the broker
    clientId: 'my_client_id',
    port: 61619,
    topic: `some/topic`,
}

let client = mqtt.connect(config.host, {
    username: config.username,
    password: config.password,
    clientId: config.clientId,
})

let message = JSON.stringify({
    message: "Hello from Lambda"
})

client.on('connect', function() {
    client.publish(config.topic, message)
    client.end()
})

console.log("Product script has been run");
```

First I run the consumer: `node consumer.js`.

After that I run: `node producer.js`.

I am not seeing anything in the console/terminal. When I run `node consumer.js` I could only see `Consumer script has been run` in the terminal.

Also when I run `node producer.js` I only saw `Producer script has been run`. It seems like the connection was not formed.

What is wrong with my code/ configuration and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this locally with ActiveMQ Artemis, and the first thing I had to change was the connection URL. I tested with both `ws://localhost:1883` and `mqtt://localhost:1883` and either one resulted in a successful connection.

However, the next problem with your two clients is that they are both using the **same client ID** (i.e. `my_client_id`). Only one client at a time can use a particular client ID. What's happening is that after the consumer connects with `my_client_id` the producer also connects with `my_client_id` which *disconnects* the consumer. Then the producer sends a message and disconnects at which point the consumer reconnects. However, since the consumer wasn't connected when the message was sent it doesn't receive it.

Also, you need to define `topic` in your `consumer.js`.

Lastly, you should confirm that you're using the right port. Currently you're attempting to connect to port `61619`, but the default MQTT port is `1883` for non-SSL and `8883` for SSL.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I corrected the topic in consumer.js and client_id in both scripts. I also checked the endpoints and I am using the right ports. It still does not work. Could this be some sort of AWS related issues?

Comment: I also tried with this, `mqtt+ssl://b-xxxxxx-d21c-xxxx-xxxx-eda5de73ea53-1.mq.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883`. still does not work.

Comment: It's working as expected now actually. I just needed to update the security group. Thanks

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as correct to help other users who encounter similar issues in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted it. It was not the answered but helpful. The issue was AWS related.

Comment: You asked about how to fix _your code_. The fact that you reused the client ID and did not define the `topic` variable were real problems with your code. Given the information you provided in your question it would be impossible to deduce that there was a problem with the back-end security configuration, and either way that's not what you asked about. Without fixing the code the applications still wouldn't have worked even if the back-end security problem was resolved.